# Does clearing a thread list destroy my threads

Tags: c++11, stl, pthreads

I have a `list<thread>` list of threads in c++ for threadpool. If I use the clear() function on the list, does it destroy all my threads as well or do I need to explicitly kill them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is `thread` a `std::thread`?  The standard says this about the the destructor:

> If `joinable()`, calls `terminate()`.

This means that you need to join the threads first before deallocating the thread objects.  So yes, you have to “kill” them, or, more likely, arrange that they exit in an orderly fashion.

Comment: But I am detaching my threads earlier. Won't that make them non-joinable?
And if so, how do I go around killing all my threads from another (for eg. main) thread.